# Create an array of file nodes in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, file, graphql, schema, gatsby

I am new to GraphQL and Gatsby and struggling with the concept of creating multiple remote file nodes from Markdown.

```markdown
---
title: Blog Post
images:
  - https://example.org/1.jpg
  - https://example.org/2.jpg
  - https://example.org/3.jpg
---

Blog content
```

Given the above MDX file for a blog post, I want to display an image gallery on the page. All images are located in remote sources, so I need to create remote file nodes first and update the schema:

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  createTypes(`
    type Mdx implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
      fields: Fields
      images: [File] @link(from: "fields.localFile")
    }

    type Frontmatter {
      title: String
      images: [String]
    }

    type Fields {
      slug: String
    }
  `);
```

Then, I iterate over all MDX files that have the `images` property and create the needed nodes:

```js
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions,
  store,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
}) => {
  const { createNodeField, createNode } = actions;

  if (node.internal.type === "Mdx" && node.frontmatter.images) {
    const imageNodes = [];

    for (let image of node.frontmatter.images) {
      const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
        url: image,
        parentNodeId: node.id,
        createNode,
        createNodeId,
        cache,
        store,
      });

      if (fileNode) {
        imageNodes.push(fileNode);
      }
    }

    createNodeField({ node, name: "localFile", value: imageNodes });
  }
};
```

So far so good, the `images` field appears in GraphiQL and has the right type (seeing things like `childImageSharp` etc.). However, when trying to query the images, I receive the following error:

```
query MyQuery {
  allMdx {
    nodes {
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
      images {
        absolutePath
      }
    }
  }
}

--> "Unable to serialize object as a key"
```

I am sure that it's something I messed up with the schema or node creation, but I have a hard time wrapping my head around it - could someone explain to me how this can be set up correctly? Is it even possible to have an array of file nodes for images?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to push .id

```
if (fileNode) {
        imageNodes.push(fileNode.id);
      }
```

then it should work quite fine